# How to detect the cell format like General, Percentage, currency ... in xlrd

Tags: python-3.x, xlrd

[screenshot from Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7bKv.png)
I'm using xlrd python library, and I want to get information about the cell format like :General, Percentage, Currency, ...

From the library doc, I found the following

style_name_map = {}
This provides access via name to the extended format information for both built-in styles and user-defined
styles.
It maps name to (built_in, xf_index), where name is either the name of a user-defined style, or
the name of one of the built-in styles. Known built-in names are Normal, RowLevel_1 to RowLevel_7,
ColLevel_1 to ColLevel_7, Comma, Currency, Percent, “Comma [0]”, “Currency [0]”, Hyperlink, and
“Followed Hyperlink”.

but I could not find a way to use this information to know the format of the cell

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
xf = book.xf_list[cell.xf_index]
fmt_key = xf.format_key
fmt = book.format_map[fmt_key]
return fmt.format_str
```